# Django Many-to-many limiting choices on a formset so forced removal of inactive?

Tags: django, formset, inline-formset

The requirement is a `many-to-many` relationship between `users` and `projects`.

Both `User` and `Project` model have an `is_active` attribute.

There is an inline formset when editing the `User` and `Project` with an updateview.

The `many-to-many` field is controlled through an intermediate table.

On `User` model:

```
projects = models.ManyToManyField(
        Project,
        through=ProjectMembership
    )
```

On `Project` model:

```
users = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        through='ProjectMembership'
    )
```

On `ProjectMembership` intermediate model I am setting the `limit_choices_to`:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        limit_choices_to={'is_active': True},
)
project = models.ForeignKey(
    Project,
    on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    limit_choices_to={'is_active': True},
)
```

On the formset a user can only be assigned to a new project and the same the other way around.
The problem comes in with existing project that were made inactive.

So you can save active projects to a user:

[image: Save active projects to a project]

But when you change the `is_active` status of `Stackoverflow Answering` to `False`:

[image: The option does not exists]

And then when you try to save it forces you to delete the row:

[image: Forced deleting of formset row inactive]

Ideally I want `inactive` project to be `disabled` or not visible at all.

Which would mean overriding the `get_initial_data` or `initial queryset`.
Also they wouldn't be validated with the `clean` method. How can I specifically fix this?

The `Formset`:

```
class ProjectMembershipForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectMembership
        fields = (
            'user',
            'project',
            'is_project_manager',
        )


ProjectMembershipFormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(
    Project,
    ProjectMembership,
    form=ProjectMembershipForm,
    extra=1,
    can_delete=True
)
```

The `UserUpdateView`:

```
class UserUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = get_user_model()
    form_class = forms.UserUpdateForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['projectmembership_formset'] = forms.UserProjectMembershipFormSet(
                self.request.POST,
                instance=self.object
            )
        else:
            context['projectmembership_formset'] = forms.UserProjectMembershipFormSet(
                instance=self.object
            )
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        '''Handle saving of the project membership formset
        '''
        context = self.get_context_data()
        project_memberships = context['projectmembership_formset']
        if project_memberships.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            project_memberships.instance = self.object
            project_memberships.save()
            return super().form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you doing your form? Class-based view? UpdateView? FormView? If you post your view-code I'll be able to give a much better answer.

If you're using any sort of form-view, the solution should be pretty easy. You'll just need to pass the desired queryset into the formfield as an argument.

```
class AddProjectToUserForm(forms.form):
    projects = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Partner.objects.filter(is_active=True))
```

EDIT: for a modelForm try this:

```
class ProjectMembershipForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectMembership
        fields = (
            'user',
            'project',
            'is_project_manager',
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectMembershipForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['project'].queryset = Project.objects.filter(is_active=True)
        self.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.filter(is_active=True)
```

`self.fields` holds references to all the fields on a form, and lets you override properties like `disabled` before sending them off to the browser. If you want to see more about that, put an `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` into the init method and wander around `self.fields`.

I hope that helps.

EDIT TWO:
In that case, you should try other modifications to the field in **init**. What about setting the field as disabled if its "initial" data is illegal?

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProjectMembershipForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    project = self.fields['project']
    if projcet.initial and project.initial not in project.queryset:
        project.disabled = True
```

I'm not positive that will work, but something like it should do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately `inlineformset_factory` does not take `queryset` as an argument

Comment: The `ProjectMembership` model is already doing the limiting / filtering of the queryset. The problem I am facing is that if an enabled project is assigned to a user. Then it subsequently becomes disabled. I don't want the user to be forced to manually delete that row. I want it ignored.